# Python Package: Get the country based on adress(non-ip)

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation

I'm searching for python package that can help me get the country from the address.

I use pycountry but I could used only if I have the country in the address, but I don't know what to do if I have, for ex:

"Georgetown, TX" , "Santa Fe, New Mexico", "Nuremberg", "Haarbergstr. 67 D-99097 Erfurt".

I don't know what to do when I have no country in address, and no clear pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems [geopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy) can do it relatively easily. An example adopted from the [documentation](http://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
>>> import geopy   
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim   
>>> gl = Nominatim()   
>>> l = gl.geocode("Georgetown, TX")   
    # now we have l = Location((30.671598, -97.6550065012, 0.0))
>>> l.address
[u'Georgetown', u' Williamson County', u' Texas', u' United States of America']
# split that address on commas into a list, and get the last item (i.e. the country)
>>> l.address.split(',')[-1]
u' United States of America'
```

We got it! Now, test it on other locations

```
>>> l = gl.geocode("Santa Fe, New Mexico")
l.address.split(',')[-1]
u' United States of America'
>>> l = gl.geocode("Nuremberg")
>>> l.address.split(',')[-1]
u' Deutschland'
>>> l = gl.geocode("Haarbergstr. 67 D-99097 Erfurt")
>>> l.address.split(',')[-1]
u' Europe'
```

So you could automate the list in a script:

```
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()

list_of_locations = "Georgetown, TX" , "Santa Fe, New Mexico", "Nuremberg", "Haarbergstr. 67 D-99097 Erfurt"

for loc in list_of_locations:
    location = geolocator.geocode(loc)
    fulladdress = location.address
    country = fulladdress.split(',')[-1]
    print '{loc}: {country}'.format(loc=loc, country=country)
```

Output:

```
Georgetown, TX:  United States of America
Santa Fe, New Mexico:  United States of America
Nuremberg:  Deutschland
Haarbergstr. 67 D-99097 Erfurt:  Europe
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: geopy is not working in most cases, for example width: "A.J. Tuck Co. Brookfield,Ct United States 06804-1814". Definitely is and United States adress, but the result is none; It is working if I remove the company name and number, but it doesn't help me because I don't have a clear pattern to remove strings like company names from address

Comment: For that example which already has the country in the string, could you just extract the country from the string? Using string parsing, or a regex?

Comment: 1) yes, but that means I have to build myself a list of countries and their name variations; - i can use pycountry for that, but -> 2) if I remove the country form the string I will receive also none, so 1) is not the main issue, is just an example; 3) the issues it's not with the package itself but with the services - I tried more of them and each one of them have different issues and using different names for country, so it is harder to recycle trough more of them; 4) Nominatim is the best as response time, with GoogleV3 and Yahoo I received a lots of timeout.

Comment: Seems like you could parse though your entire list of data using one strategy, with `try/except` Exception Handling, and anything that succeeds the `try` case potentially gets accepted...and anything that gets excepted in the `except` case you could save into a new list and handle them on a case-by-case basis. That may help narrow down your data to the individual cases that you would use different strategies to complete your task.